# 'No suitable driver' exception implementing Olap4J XMLA Server

Tags: olap, mondrian, olap4j

I'm trying to implement [olap4j-xmlaserver](http://github.com/olap4j/olap4j-xmlaserver) to access Mondrian via HTTP/XMLA. I compiled the project, created a war file (including a `web.xml` file) and deployed it in Tomcat 7. Problem is that I'm getting an exception when the pivot client application sends an XMLA request:

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:mondrian:Jdbc=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foodmart?user=root&password=xxx;Catalog=/WEB-INF/FoodMart.xml'
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
        at mondrian.xmla.impl.Olap4jXmlaServlet$Olap4jPoolingConnectionFactory.getConnection(Olap4jXmlaServlet.java:300)
        at mondrian.xmla.XmlaHandler.getConnection(XmlaHandler.java:2917)
        ... 33 more 

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver (DriverManager.java:315)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
        ... 37 more
```

The `web.xml` I put together (I couldn't find a sample in the `olap4j-xmlaserver` project). I'm sure this `web.xml` file needs to be fixed to solve the problem, especially the connection string:

```
<web-app ....

  <display-name>olap4j-xmlaserver</display-name>
  <description>
     Olap4J XML/A server
  </description>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>xmla</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>mondrian.xmla.impl.Olap4jXmlaServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
       <param-name>OlapDriverClassName</param-name>
       <param-value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
       <param-name>OlapDriverConnectionString</param-name>
       <param-value>
         jdbc:mondrian:Jdbc=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foodmart?user=root&amp;password=xxx;Catalog=/WEB-INF/FoodMart.xml
       </param-value>
    </init-param>   
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>xmla</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/xmla</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Any ideas how to fix the `web.xml` configuration  or pointers to relevant documentation will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the Java driver for MySQL in your classpath. Add it to your webapp in the folder named 'WEB-INF/lib'.

Comment: I already had the jar in the classpath, this didn't solve the problem